# How to insert string into the output string stream

Tags: java, stringstream, printwriter

I want to simply write code that inserts my userItems into the output string stream itemsOSS. Each of my item will be followed by a space. I want the output to reflect the following for example,  "red purple yellow Exit":

Output example,

red purple yellow

```java
public class StringStreamOutput {

   public static void main (String [] args) {

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userItem = "";

      StringWriter itemCharStream = new StringWriter();
      PrintWriter itemsOSS = new PrintWriter(itemCharStream);

      System.out.println("Enter items (type Exit to quit):");
      userItem = scnr.next();

      while (!userItem.equals("Exit")) {

         // confused here, 

         userItem = scnr.next();
      }

      userItem = itemCharStream.toString();
      System.out.println(userItem);

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is "output string stream itemsOSS" ? I don't see anything that reflects something like that in your code.

Comment: PrintWriter has a print(String) method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(java.lang.String). So what's the concrete problem?

Comment: I found the code that works, I just needed to utilize the print method. 

      itemsOSS.print(userItem + " ");
      
      userItem = itemCharStream.toString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the code that works, I just needed to utilize the print method.

```java
itemsOSS.print(userItem + " "); 

userItem = itemCharStream.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class StringStreamOutput {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String userItem;

      StringWriter itemCharStream = new StringWriter();
      PrintWriter itemsOSS = new PrintWriter(itemCharStream);

      System.out.println("Enter items (type Exit to quit):");
      userItem = scnr.next();

      while (!userItem.equals("Exit")) {

         /* Your solution goes here  */
         itemsOSS.print(userItem + " ");


         /* this does not to be added as it sits outside the loop
         userItem = itemCharStream.toString();
         */

         userItem = scnr.next();
      }

      userItem = itemCharStream.toString();
      System.out.println(userItem);
   }
}
```

This works

Comment: Can you explain it a bit Robert?

Comment: Sure. The only actual thing I added was `itemsOSS.print(userItem + " ")`. This uses the **PrintWriter** to modify its parameter of **ItemCharString**. Then `userItem` is assigned the `itemCharString` and also calls it `toString()` method to later be printed as a string. The rest of the code is what the user provided in the original question. And I **multi-line commented** out the code `userItem = itemCharString.toString()` because it was already declared outside of the while loop and therefore was just redundant code.

Comment: Sorry I can also explain a bit more on the one line I added. So the `itemOSS.print(userItem + " ")` calls forth the **PrintWriter** that has a parameter of the **StringWriters** `itemCharString`. This will modify the `itemCharString` with the parameters of `userItem` and then add a space between each call of the loop. Because of this we can leave the other `userItem = itemCharString.toString();` code out of the loop because we are directly modifying `itemCharString` through the **PrintWriters** parameter.